# What's the difference between ConnectEx and _ConnectEx?

Tags: windows, winapi

I've found some code that uses _ConnectEx and not the normal ConnectEx.

Is there a difference?

In fact I've noticed that Microsoft have some other function calls that are preceded by an underscore.  What is the motivation for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ConnectEx` isn't a normal exported function. In fact it's not exported by name at all. If you read the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737606.aspx) for it you find:

> The function pointer for the ConnectEx function must be obtained at
>   run time by making a call to the WSAIoctl function with the
>   SIO_GET_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_POINTER opcode specified. The input buffer
>   passed to the WSAIoctl function must contain WSAID_CONNECTEX, a
>   globally unique identifier (GUID) whose value identifies the ConnectEx
>   extension function. On success, the output returned by the WSAIoctl
>   function contains a pointer to the ConnectEx function.

So I would say that the code you have seen is simply using a variable called `_ConnectEx` to store the function address.